# Keep null as empty and convert nvarchar to date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

`expiredDate nvarchar()` column contains data like `22-12-2022 00:00:00` and null.

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(Date, expiredDate), '') 
FROM tablename
```

Result for null is default date `1900-01-01` - I want it to be blank or empty.

As the column is getting converted to datetime null is converted to the default date.
Required date should be in yyyy-MM-dd format and null as empty

Comment: Why don't you leave it as null? "Blank" is a string, not a date

Comment: I would fix the real problem: Change field `expiredDate` to a `DATE` data type in the database.

Comment: You should leave the formatting to the front end. Anytime you start formatting dates as strings and sending them back you are in for a long battle. Things like sorting will be totally broken in the application if you get strings back instead of dates. Just don't do this.

Comment: @SeanLange would have loved to leave it in the front end but the issue never see's the front end. it is a script which plays and gets the output for the third party.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `CONVERT` here on the raw date to generate a string, and then `COALESCE` missing null values into empty string:

```sql
SELECT expiredDate,
       COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(10), expiredDate, 120), '') AS expiredDateText
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: This works for the date getting in format dd-mm-yyyy how can we change it to yyyy-MM-dd format while doing so

Comment: @VedRaut My code in fact should be generating date strings in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format already, see the [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=170db5b3c370ab3c8f76fd07b09e75ed).

Comment: @VedRaut converting the date format should be done in the User Interface (web page, SSRS Report, etc.) and not in the query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think this will work as ```expiredDate``` is stored as ```NVARCHAR``` instead of ```DATE```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query.

```
select case when ISDATE(expiredDate) = 0 then '' else convert(varchar,convert(date,expiredDate)) end as YourColumnName
```

The ISDATE() function checks whether the input data is a valid date or not. This includes NULL too. It will return Zero (0) if the data is ***not a date***.

If you culture is en-us then by default you will get the date in YYYY-MM-DD format.
You can also use Format function in SQL Server to get the date in your expected format.

More information about format function can be found at below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Two notes. First, I highly recommend NOT using ISDATE() as it has a lot of quirks that aren't intuitive. Try running ```Select CASE WHEN ISDATE('2000') = 1 THEN 'Valid' ELSE 'Invalid' END```. It returns **Valid**, which is very counterintutive and probably not desired behavior.  One of the newer *TRY* functions like ```TRY_CAST()``` I think is much safer. Secondly, OP requested NULL be represented by blank string not NULL, but your query will still returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

You've have stumbled upon one of the odd(annoying) quirks in SQL Server where blank string becomes 1900-01-01 when cast to DATE. Your CONVERT() sets the column type to DATE, and then when you do ISNULL, it implicitly casts empty string to DATE. Why it returns 1900-01-01 instead of an error, I have no idea

### Example of Empty String to Date Odd Behavior

```
SELECT CAST('' AS DATE)

--Returns 1900-01-01
```

### Parse Date to Correct DATE data type and Then Format

How I'd recommend this is first converting your NVARCHAR column to the correct DATE data type. Using TRY_CAST allows any invalid dates to not cause the whole query to fail, instead will return NULL. FORMAT() then allows you to format the DATE anyway you like, and ISNULL will change NULL to empty string

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),expiredDate nvarchar(20))
INSERT INTO @YourTable 
VALUES ('22-12-2022 00:00:00'),('31-12-2022 00:00:00'),('02-02-2022 00:00:00'),(NULL)
,('40-02-2022 00:00:00') /*Bad date for testing purposes*/

SELECT *,FormattedExpiredDate = ISNULL(FORMAT(B.ExpiredDateWithCorrectDateType,'yyyy-MM-dd'),'')
FROM @YourTable AS A
/*Format to YYYY-MM-DD (culture agnostic date format) and then use TRY_CAST(). If date is invalid, will return NULL*/
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ExpiredDateWithCorrectDateType = TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(expiredDate,7,4) + SUBSTRING(expiredDate,4,2) + SUBSTRING(expiredDate,1,2) AS DATE)) AS B
```

**Results:**

| ID | expiredDate | ExpiredDateWithCorrectDateType | FormattedExpiredDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22-12-2022 00:00:00 | 2022-12-22 | 2022-12-22 |
| 2 | 31-12-2022 00:00:00 | 2022-12-31 | 2022-12-31 |
| 3 | 02-02-2022 00:00:00 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-02-02 |
| 4 | NULL | NULL |  |
| 5 | 40-02-2022 00:00:00 | NULL |  |